# Discrete Math - non-negative intergers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the number of non-negative integer solutions to
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 3$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) $\;$

Answer (score 2):

We have set 1,1,1,0,0,0, set 2,1,0,0,0,0 and set 3,0,0,0,0,0 as solutions.

For the first set there are:

$$\binom{6}{3} = 20 \text{ combinations}$$

For the second there are:

$$6 \times 5 = 30 \text{ combinations}$$

And for the third there are:

$$\binom{6}{1} = 6 \text{ combinations}$$

That's total of 56 solutions.

Comment: In this particular case, your answer is probably the easiest solution. $\;$

Comment: The number $3$ is so small that this may be what is intended, in preparation for introduction of Stars and Bars.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this problem like count the number of ways of putting $3$  indistinguishable elements into $6$ distinguishable boxes.